# Translate cURL request to Guzzle

Tags: guzzle

I am trying to use Guzzle instead of directly using cURL to achieve and HTTP request. How do I make this same type of request but with Guzzle? Or should I just stick to cURL?

```
$ch = curl_init();
// Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// don't verify SSL certificate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
// Return the contents of the response as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// Follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
// Set up authentication
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$token:X");
```

I keep running into 401 Unauthorized error.  I know I have correct credentials. What makes me think I am not on the right track is the Guzzle docs stating: *auth is currently only supported when using the cURL handler, but creating a replacement that can be used with any HTTP handler is planned.* But from my understanding Guzzle defaults with cURL.

```
$guzzleData = [
  'auth' => [$token, 'X'],
  'allow_redirects' => true,
  'verify' => false,
];

$client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client();
$request = $client->get($url, $guzzleData);
$response = $request->send();
```

Comment: You probably get more answers for your question when posting on Stack Exchange, voted to migrate.

Comment: As mentioned by @carlcs, this question is a much better fit on Stack Overflow. While helpful to some Craft plugin devs, it's really not a Craft question per se.

Comment: Nice! I was able to up vote twice, once on Craft SE and now here! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client();
$request = $client->get($url);

$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$token:X");

$response = $request->send();
```

Comment: this answer does not work with current guzzlehttp

Comment: Is this working for an old version like guzzle 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was able to get working for Guzzle6 is:

```
$headers = array();
$headers['grant_type'] = 'client_credentials';
$headers['client_id'] = $clientid;
$headers['client_secret'] = $clientSecret;

$response = $this->client->post($urlAuth, ['form_params' => $headers]);
$output = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

ie the header array has to be wrapped in 'form_params'

Comment: I don't see what `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is translated to