# Guzzle 6 result returns with HTTP Headers

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm having a problem with how Guzzle 6.x returns my results, due to this I am receiving "Syntax Error" when I try to `json_decode` my results. I have used `var_dump()` and `print_r()` to get my actual results and it turns out that my JSON results returns with a HTTP Header included in it. Actual results below:

```
string(486) "Array
(
    [Content-Type] => application/json
    [Content-Length] => 23
    [X-Auth-Key] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [X-Apikey] => XXXXXXXXX
    [User-Agent] => GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.54.0 PHP/7.1.23
    [Host] => example.com
)
{
    "message": {
        "value": "successful",
        "status_code": "200"
    },
    "details": {
        "status": [
            "00:00|Data 1|"
        ]
    }
}"
```

I've done my research and I've tried altering my code I've tried the following:

```php
$result = (string) $response->getBody(); // 1

$result = $response->getBody()->getContents(); // 2
```

Below is my code on how I send HTTP requests to my server:

```php
$response = $this->client->post('', [RequestOptions::JSON => $data]);
$result = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$contents = json_decode($result); // this returns NULL and syntax error
```

My expected results should be this:

```
{
    "message": {
        "value": "successful",
        "status_code": "200"
    },
    "details": {
        "status": [
            "00:00|Data 1|"
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope you'll be able to help me.

Comment: Have you tried `$request = $client->postt('', [RequestOptions::JSON => $data]);
$response = $request->send();
echo $response->getBody();`

Comment: It's look like you need to add CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option for the guzzle. Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752981/translate-curl-request-to-guzzle how it is done

Comment: I've tried both and it still doesn't seem to work. My results still returns the HTTP Headers in Array

Comment: Are you sure that it's not part of the response itself? Is it possible for us to know the uri that you are requesting? If you try to `curl` it directly from command line, do you get only json in the body of the response?

Comment: @Federkun Yes I'm sure as when I tried it on Postman it only returns the expected response

Comment: I'm afraid we may need more details on this one. Just to be sure, your use of `$raw` in your example is just a spelling mistake of `$result` ( that contains the real response )?

Comment: @Federkun that's all the info I can give as that's everything I had do to send a POST request on my server. Also, thanks for pointing it out, it's a typo while I was typing the question

Comment: can we see how `$this->client` is created? are you using any custom middleware?

Comment: @Federkun $this->client is ```GuzzleHttp\Client``` which I re-initiated on another class after I created a configuration which included the base_uri and header credentials as required by the API I'm calling. And no, I'm not using any custom middleware